# How to use navigator.langugage for localization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, localization, navigator

I am trying to use navigator.langauge in react and I want to show greeting message in their local language by default and greetings should be according to hour. Can we use navigator.lang to do so?

I have tired react i18 but it doesn't work in chrome extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a multilingual sample.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "__MSG_extName__",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "default_locale": "en",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body style="min-width:400px">
  <div id="hello"></div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
const hello = chrome.i18n.getMessage("hello");
document.getElementById("hello").innerText = hello;
```

_locales\en\messages.json

```json
{
  "extName": {
    "message": "Hello."
  },
  "hello": {
    "message": "Hello."
  }
}
```

_locales\ja\messages.json

```json
{
  "extName": {
    "message": "こんにちは。"
  },
  "hello": {
    "message": "こんにちは。"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.language` is going to give you a string representing the language and dialect (example: `en-US`) that the user's browser is set to. If you want to just grab the language part (not the dialect), you could do this:

```
navigator.language.split('-').shift()
```

And it should give you just give you the "en" part.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I got this part, suppose people have different different language in their browser then how can I will translate it to their particular language.

Comment: There is not any native API in JavaScript to take a string and translate it. You'd have to have multiple translations (that you've created) and use logic to decide which to show. Or you'd have to have another library or API to translate dynamically.

Comment: What I have done sometimes is create a file for each language that I want to support, each with a JSON file. The JSON file would just be a key-value object with the key being some string describing the phrase and the value being the translated text for that language. And then, based on the user's language, it would load the appropriate JSON file and pull the key-value pair for the string I want.